# In this context, would tes or vos be more appropriate?

Tags: choix-de-mot, adjectifs

In addition to my [previous question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28293/which-is-more-idiomatic-au-lieu-or-au-lieu-de-cela), let's say a parent tells their child, "Stop watching TV. Instead, do your homework." We could translate this into French as,

> Arrête de regarder la télé. Au lieu de cela, faites tes devoirs.

In this context, which would be more appropriate: *tes devoirs* or *vos devoirs*?

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing two sentences here.

It's either:

Arrête de regarder la télé et fais plutôt tes devoirs (ou va plutôt faire tes devoirs)

or:

Arrêtez de regarder la télé et faites vos devoirs.

Comment: Why must it be one sentence and not two?

Comment: You're focusing on the wrong issue. You're mixing up tu and vous, which is the main issue. Arrête is tutoiement (singulier) and thus it has to be "fais tes". I think you need to go back to basics and (re)learn the difference between tu and vous.

Comment: Because it is not correct to mix the verbs and possessive articles in the singular and the plural (or, the *vous* form) : they are adressed to the same person(s), so you have to keep the same form. Use either *arrête/fais* (and then *tes*) or *arrêtez/faites* (and then *vos*), but you cannot mix both. It would be like addressing someone first as "tu", then "vous", it is wrong.

Comment: @user45785 There is a single child here. Parents are very unlikely to say *vous* to him / her.

Comment: I was just covering the possibilities. But a blueblood might well say that even today. A joke is also possible.

Comment: In which case it would be *Arrête**z***, not Arrête. You can mix them up. Plus, "bluebloods", as you call them, don't say *vous* to their children. Children *might* use vous.

Comment: I wrote Arrêtez, didn't I?! And yes, they do.